# Where is the most appropriate place to stored an authenticated user's access token in an iOS App?

Tags: ios

I have an API that returns an access token upon successful authentication (username, password). I am building an iOS app that authenticates with this API. Where would be the most appropriate place to store this access token, and how would I implement it? It seems that `NSUserDefaults` would be pretty easy to use, but it seems intended for storing user preferences.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Any sensitive data should be stored in keychain. You are correct, NSUserDefaults is easy for a hacker to read. Take a look at https://github.com/soffes/sskeychain.

A more barebones approach is to use the wrapper apple provides. https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/samplecode/GenericKeychain/Listings/Classes_KeychainItemWrapper_h.html

This shows more of the implementation, but requires some tedious code.

Also if you're using swift.
https://github.com/deniskr/KeychainSwiftAPI